# Angular 4.0 Rxjs variables undefined

Tags: angular, rxjs

After upgrading to angular 4.0 i am getting errors for RxJs variables.  Everything builds fine.  But when i load the page i get this error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'forkJoin' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'forkJoin' of undefined

i am using forkJoin in an init function

```
init(){
  return Observable.forKJoin()
}
```

I import the Observable at the top and it looks like this

> import {Observable,Observer,Subject,BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/Rx';

what changes were made that would all of a sudden cause these issues.  My code runs fine pre 4.0

Comment: import the forkJoin operator from 'rxjs'

Comment: Are you really importing from `'rxjs/Rx'`? That file includes [all of the side-effect imports for the operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.2.0/src/Rx.ts#L11-L141) so you should not have the problem you've described.

Answer (score 0):

rxjs has a bit of a "choose what you want to import" approach to Observables. Basically it's a Decorator pattern where you import the base Observable and then you import all the fancy things you want it to do. In addition to importing the observable, you also need to import:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
```

I usually have an `rxjs-operators.ts` file that I just import anytime I need anything from it.

Older versions of rxjs didn't work like this. I believe it was sometime during v2's RC period rxjs switched to this model.

All of these extra imports are part of the rxjs package so you won't need to download anything new or add anything to your package.json to access them.

Comment: I am using rxjs 5.0.1 which version are you using.  importing forkjoin didnt seem to work.  The error leads me to believe that Observable is undefined for some reason

Comment: I have `^5.1.0` in my package.json for rxjs. That's the version that the latest angular-cli gives me.